# Center div below div

Tags: html, css, menu, margin

Hello and sorry for my bad english in advance.

I am having trouble with some code.
What I've got is a header  with a background-image (logo) - div.

Underneath that I've got a menu - div.
The header is 770px centered
The menu is supposed to be centered underneath the header.

[Exaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcFfY.png)

```
    <div id="header"><div>
<br>

<br>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Forside</a></li>
    <li><a href="priser.php">Priser</a></li>
    <li><a href="bestil.php">Bestil / Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

- HTML part.

---

```
body{
background-color:#fff;
color:#000;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:10px;
background:url('viking.png') left no-repeat;
}

a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
a:link{text-decoration:none; font-family:verdana; font-weight:normal; }
#header{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-image:url('/head.png');
width: 770px;
height: 130px;
margin-top:-10px;
}

#menu{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:116px;
text-align:center;
width:770px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#menu ul{
list-style:none;
}
#menu ul li{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#menu ul li a { padding:20px; background: rgba(255,138,30,0.3); text-decoration: none; font: bold 24px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: -1px; color: #402e16;
```

- Full CSS part.

I'm pretty desperate and hope for help!

Comment: Try putting them together in a container and adding `text-align: center;` to the entire thing.  Make the width of the container match the width of the page so it's fully centered.

Comment: Why are you floating the list items to the left if you don't want them on the left? Remove the float. Problem solved.

Comment: oh my god that simple float-tag did it. I did nott see it - not my code.. However, thank you oGeez!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `float:left` from your `#menu ul li`

http://jsfiddle.net/bW73N/